# Removing and adding buttons using loops behaving oddly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to code a quiz with 4 options and *x* questions. Currently, you click on the button, it pops up, and a function deletes the buttons and a recalls the function to recreate them with different text. The first one looks similar to a normal quiz, and then all formatting goes out the window.

The different button layout is not deliberate, and I can't work out why the top text is disappearing (would like it to though)

Code (sorry for the mass js in HTML):

```js
let q = 0;
let ans = [
  ["CompSci", "Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry"],
  ["Javascript", "Ruby", "Python", "C#"],
  ["Easy", "Difficult", "Hard", "Impossible"],
  ["Good", "Bad", "Really bad", "The literal worst"]
];
var questions = [
  ["Favourite lesson", "Language I don't know", "Writing this code", "The quality of this quiz"],
  [2, 4, 4, 4]
];
let count = 0;
var qType;

function setQuestion() {
  document.write("Question Number ", q + 1, );
  document.write('<br>');
  document.write(questions[0][q]);
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
  var t = document.createTextNode(ans[q][0]); // Create a text node
  btn.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <button>
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  document.write('<br>');

  var btn2 = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
  var t2 = document.createTextNode(ans[q][1]); // Create a text node
  btn2.appendChild(t2); // Append the text to <button>
  document.body.appendChild(btn2);
  document.write('<br>');

  var btn3 = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
  var t3 = document.createTextNode(ans[q][2]); // Create a text node
  btn3.appendChild(t3); // Append the text to <button>
  document.body.appendChild(btn3);
  document.write('<br>');

  var btn4 = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
  var t4 = document.createTextNode(ans[q][3]); // Create a text node
  btn4.appendChild(t4); // Append the text to <button>
  document.body.appendChild(btn4);

  qType = questions[1][q];
  switch (qType) {
    case 1:
      btn.addEventListener("click", Right);
      btn2.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn3.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn4.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      break;
    case 2:
      btn.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn2.addEventListener("click", Right);
      btn3.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn4.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      break;
    case 3:
      btn.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn2.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn3.addEventListener("click", Right);
      btn4.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      break;
    case 4:
      btn.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn2.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn3.addEventListener("click", Wrong);
      btn4.addEventListener("click", Right);
      break;
    default:
  }

  function Wrong() {
    alert("WRONG!")
    Reset()
  }

  function Right() {
    alert("RIGHT!");
    count++;
    Reset()
  }

  function Reset() {
    btn.remove();
    btn2.remove();
    btn3.remove();
    btn4.remove();
    q = q + 1;
    if (q >= questions[0].length) {
      alert(count.toString() + "/" + (questions[0].length).toString())
    } else {
      setQuestion();
    }
  }
}

setQuestion();
```

```css
{
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

p.question {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2E2E2E;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2.quizHeader {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
}

h2.quizScore {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

label {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #424242;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input.answer[type="radio"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Questions {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

th {}

tr {}

td {}

.hide {
  display: none;
}


/*SFS light red = #c30b0a;
SFS dark red = #9f2026; */

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="quizHeader">Take a Quiz!</h2>

<div class="Questions">
```

Comment: You keep adding event listeners to the buttons; all those callbacks get called when the button is clicked. Either remove the previously added event listener, or better yet, use a single event listener function for all buttons, add it exactly once to each button at the start, then handle things inside according to which question is active and which button was clicked.

Comment: _“and then all formatting goes out the window”_ - that’s because you are using `document.write`, which when called after the initial loading of the page, replaces the complete document. So your styles embedded in the head section are gone, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `document.write` to change the content. When the *document has loaded*, `document.write` will override the full content.

You could, instead, change the content of an inner element like so:

```
document.getElementById("Questions").innerHTML = questions[0][q];
```